# How to plot several graphs of an excel data in same page in Python

Tags: python, plot

I want to plot several graphs of an excel data in Python with a simple command. My excel data contains 20 columns and 9000 rows. First, I want to choose 4th column to 20th column. Then, I want to plot 16 graphs in a single page. With the following code, I can do it by choosing manually columns and by defining subplots. But I want to do that with a simpler command(for example, I don't want to define every axes manually)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')


fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.plot(df['Column4'])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax2.plot(df['Column5'])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223)
ax3.plot(df['Column6'])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(224)
ax4.plot(df['Column7'])
for i in range(3):
    plt.subplot(2,2,i+1)
```

Do you have an idea about how can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to call the matplotlib API directly instead of through pandas if you are creating a complicated graph.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
fig, axes = plt.subplots(rows=4, cols=4, figsize=(12,12))
data_cols = df.columns[3:19]

# iterate over pairs of data columns and plot axes
for data_col, ax in zip(data_cols, axes.ravel()):
    ax.plot(df[data_col])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @James , It really worked! I want to add something, how can I add subtitles to this subplots? Subtitles will be column titles.